# Is there any way to get publishing queue in sitecore?

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, publishing, sitecore

Problem is that I use a 5.2 Sitecore, and when I start to publish something, it only shows the publishing window and a "Queued" message. There is a chance that some people full published several times(that means 15000 items and 4 slaves), and the publishing queue is stuck. The restart of the webserver/app pool is not an option.
Any experiences in sitecore publishing errors?
something like [this](http://www.mypicx.com/07232009/sitecore_publish_queued/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If several full publishes are queued then you will have to either wait and see if things finish or recycle the AppPool to start over.  Try checking your Sitecore logs to see if there is any information in there that will tell you if publishing is actually locked up or if it is just taking a while to finish.

In my experience it is *possible* to see that locked up publishing dialog and still have the publishing queue clear itself.  Unfortunately though you will most likely have to recycle the AppPool to fix this issue.

Comment: Somehow i figured out that not the publishing queue is the reason, because with the db browser(/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx) I can publish. Now I haven't got any idea.

Comment: I have also found the dbbrowser generally to be more responsive :)

Comment: sure, but the guy in tie can't use it, just the fancy "Content Manager":)

Comment: But how do you see the publish queue? E.g. if I published a bunch of content... had to log off, and come back... how do I know if that big publish finished yet?

Answer (score 1):

So the final "solution" was to be the AppPool restart. Shame that the full publish stuck the sitecore shell, but the db browser could publish. Whatever, think I should contact to some sitecore support guy. BTW thanks Andrew&Kim!

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I normaly wait until the publishing is done. But the problem is that noone knows how long time it will take.
Sometimes a reboot of the server accually does the trick, because the publish then dies. You could try to restart the server (if you have that opportunity of course) and then see if it helps. Otherwise ou have to be patient and wait until the publish queue is empty again.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to see the publishing queue on sitecorerocks - the visual studio sitecore plugin --> there is a job viewer that shows all the publishing task currently running plus the indexing task

Answer (score 0):

AppPool restart is the way to go if you would like to "kill" the publishing operation.

1. Open IIS
2. Expand the main node
3. Select "Application Pools"
4. Find and select the worker process that your site uses
5. On the right hand side hit "Recycle" under "Application Pool Tasks" header

You can also take a look at (your site)/sitecore/admin/PublishQueueStats.aspx, or (your site)/sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx - take a look on a file system, see what other administrative tools available for you in "(your web root)/sitecore/admin" folder. Might find some gems!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see all items in publish queue by using code. There is a way to get the list of item IDs in publish queue using API (Sitecore.Kernel.dll).

```
IdList publishQueue = Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.GetPublishQueue(startDate, ToDate, Context.CurrentDatabase)
```